# How to get topics by user id in bbpress?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

is anyone know how to get topics by user id in bbpress?

what I want to do is displaying the topics that created by the specified author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming bbpress means wordpress as you tagged it for wordpress:

```
<!-- Start page loop here -->
<?php
// 'post_type' => 'any' ... to display all post and custom post type related to the author or user
// You should restrict the number of post, you don't want your site crashing by loading all posts available
// I'm letting your imagination take over
$authID = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
$query = new wp_query( array( 'author' => $authID,'post_type' => 'any', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) );  if ( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<h4>Discover your feed </h4>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start page template here -->
<div><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End page template here -->
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<h4>Your feed is empty </h4>
<?php endif; ?>
<!-- End page loop here -->
```

Also this is probably a duplicate of this post, which I answered yesterday: [How to create Feed section in wordpress for homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608577/how-to-create-feed-section-in-wordpress-for-homepage/62613651#62613651)

Comment: Thanks never crossed on my mind if it's able to use wp_query, and just know yet they're using it as well.

and also this may help anyone in the future
https://pastebin.com/VHBd0uwh